# TypeScript How to use String and Object in function

Tags: javascript, typescript, string, object

Im newby in typescript

please help, how can i use object and string in function

How create functions with different props?

```
type AMessyUnion = string | { value: string, param: boolean, paramTwo: boolean  };

function (data: AMessyUnion) {
  if(data?.value) {
    // do what i need
  }
  if(typeof data === 'string' ) {
    // do what i need
  }


}
```

I have error "data doesnt contain prop value"

Comment: maybe this can help you https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-type-guards-typescript/

Comment: You can't do `data?.value` because that says "look at the `value `property of `data` (if `data` isn't `null` or `undefined`), but `string` doesn't have a `value` property. Instead, be more direct: `if (typeof data === "string") { /*...handle string...*/ } else { /*...handle array...*/ }`. If you were dealing with a union that didn't have a primitive in it (which `typeof` can help with), you can use `instanceof` in some cases (or `Array.isArray` in this case), or your own custom [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) in others.

Comment: Just put the `typeof data === 'string'` check first.